# Magento 2: Use 404 page instead of autosearch

Tags: error-handling, magento2

We run Magento 2.1.7 and have the following problem:

When an URL is entered that does not exist magento starts an autosearch with the path. We want to redirect to a 404 error page if a wrong url is entered.

example:
correct url = www.domain.com/category1/product1

when you enter the url with a spelling mistake (www.domain.com/category1/ppproduct1) magento redirects to search page and starts searching after "category1 ppproduct1"

any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score -1):

Go to admin panel and find the following option.

```
store->configuaration->web->Find the "Default Pages" option
```

**`CMS No Route Page : 404 Not Found`**

Change this setting and check. Clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this setting is already set to "404 Not Found"